# Ajax call from Spring gradle project

Tags: ajax, gradle, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Ajax call for Spring gradle project does not work?
Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/remove' + '101',
    type: 'post',
});
```

and my controller code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/remove/{code}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteBank(@RequestParam(value="code") String code) {
    System.out.println(code);
    return "bank";
}
```

Problem is controller function is not being called by AJAX URL.

I'm using `Spring Boot-Gradle-Thymeleaf`.

Comment: change `method=RequestMethod.GET` to `method=RequestMethod.POST`

Comment: I've solved the problem by myself